# Strange entries in Squid3 access.log

Tags: iptables, squid

My WiFi network for guests is transparently proxied by Squid3. There's now a girl from Indonesia with her Samsung GT-B5330 running Android 4.0.4, who gets blocked by *"The requested URL could not be retrieved" "Invalid URL"*.

Checking `access.log` I see lines like:

```
1418752070.702      0 172.16.1.66 NONE/400 3636 %C0%0E%C0%0F%C0%07%C0%09%C0 - NONE/- text/html
```

The IP is that of the router sending the requests to the proxy by iptables DNAT. And yes, the URL seems pretty invalid. The request type is also missing. However, if I allow the device to by-pass the proxy it works fine.

I did not do any deeper packet sniffing so far, since I cannot simply confiscate her mobile to experiment. So the question: Did someone see something like that before?

Squid is 3.1.6 as current in Debian 6 (Squeeze).